# What is the role of a LPF in oversampling?

Tags: sampling

Lets assume that a signal $x(n)$ is up-sampled by adding 1 zero between two adjacent samples to form a signal $y(n)$. How does a digital LPF give an oversampled version $z(n)$, with more data points? (As show in the image below) I know that the question might seem stupid but the books that I am using don't really explain that part.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effect of an ideal lowpass filter (LPF) on the output of an expander (interpolator) can be described in either of the time or frequency domains.

For the frequency-domain approach, the key observation is that the DTFT of the expanded sequence $y[n]$ of the middle figure, includes frequency-scaled and shifted copies (a.k.a **images**) of the original DTFT of the input $x[n]$. The images are centered at $\omega = 2\pi k/M$, where $M$ is the oversampling factor and $k=0,1,...,M-1$.

The LPF, whose passband includes only the base copy of the expanded spectrum, removes all the remaining surplus images, and retains only the baseband. This is accomplished in the time-domain by convolving filter's impulse reponse and signal $y[n]$, to produce $z[n]$. The cutoff frequency of the ideal LPF is given by $\omega_c = \pi/M$. In your case $w_c = \pi/2$ radians per sample, and the filter also must have a passpand gain of $M=2$ if it's to be used as an interpolation filter.

Answer (score 5):

@user29568: Your question is *very* far from stupid. It's a darned good question. To see why time-domain "zero stuffing" generates the additional spectral images, that must be filtered out as described by Fat32, you're welcome to see my explanation of this effect at: http://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/761.php

Answer (score 3):

A digital low pass FIR filter might change each added (with value zero) sample to become a weighted average of nearby original points.  A suitably weighted average is a close approximation to interpolating along a reconstructed "smooth" (or bandlimited) curve that would pass thru all the original points.  So you end up with more data points along that hypothetical curve.